# page:load does not work - jquery and turbolinks on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is a follow up question to my post 
[javascript stops working after link_to in rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19204456/javascript-stops-working-after-link-to-in-rails-4/19204972?noredirect=1#19204972)

I found this solution [Making jQuery works with Turbolinks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043134/making-jquery-works-with-turbolinks) and the one that was suggested on my previous question

I added the following code to my application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require_tree .


$(document).on('page:load', function() {
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
  });
```

now draggable is not working at all on my page

```
<div class="draggable">    
  <p><strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= task.title %></p>
  <p> <%= link_to 'Show', task, :class => 'text' %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Draggable should still work if you click a link and update the page by Turbolinks, but it won't work in initial loading because you havn't set it.

To make it work, you need to set it on both document ready and `page:load`.

```
$(document).on('page:load', function(){
  $(".draggable").draggable();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".draggable").draggable();
});
```