# Tinymce gem, Have to press reload to make tinymce toolbar available

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, tinymce, tinymce-rails

I'm using this guideline to setup tinymce in rails

https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails

but I have small problem, each time I open page that has tinymce editor, the the text area that has tinymce attached shown blank 
I have to reload / refresh the browser to make it available.

is there any tips to fix this
(I'm using rails 4)
thank you.

**tinymce.yml**

```
menubar: false
toolbar:
  - styleselect | bold italic | undo redo | table
plugins:
  - table
```

**news.html.erb**

```
<%= tinymce_assets %>
<%= form_for @news do |f| %>
    <%= render 'common/form_errors', object: @news %>
    <p>
      <%= f.label :isi %><br>
      <%= f.text_area :isi, :class => "tinymce", :rows => 7, :cols => 50 %>
      <%= tinymce :content_css => asset_path('application.css') %>
    </p>
  <div class="form-action">
    <%= f.submit nil, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making jQuery works with Turbolinks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043134/making-jquery-works-with-turbolinks)

Comment: thank you for give me an idea about my problem, yes it's turbolink issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I just fixed the issue, it's because of turbolink
so for every link that point to the page that has tinymce attached 
I disable turbolink by this option 'data-no-turbolink' => true

```
<%= link_to "Create News", new_news_path, 'data-no-turbolink' => true %>
```

Comment: You should either disable turbo links totally or learn to live with them. Half-solutions will cause headache in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative could be this:

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
   tinymce.remove();
   tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});
});
```

Comment: This solution does not work on rails 5 - i'm experimenting with TinyMCE combined with the prism gem